# Using only SOME classes from jar for CDI injection

Tags: java, cdi

I want to move useful CDI components from a project to a separate JAR and reuse them in other projects.

Is there a way for the *using* project to control which components (e.g. producers) from the JAR will be available in its container?

I'm searching for something like the inverse of beans.xml. Something like an **import** descriptor.

What I've tried:

- qualifiers: they are not very handy in my case
- classes in JAR without CDI annotations (e.g. @Produces) and empty subclasses with annotation in the *using* project

Any other ideas?

Comment: `@Alternative` and whoever wants to use specific components can declare the `@Alternative` beans in its own `beans.xml`

Comment: What is the use-case? Just curious. Since development time everyone still has all freedom.

Comment: The use case is a sw company building some apps based on JavaEE >=7 and CDI. Over time common components were developed and we tried to extract them to one or more extra JARs. Not all of the apps need all of the components of one JAR automatically. They want to control which are used and which not. In case of producers this is not trivial as there may be more producers for the same product.

Answer (score 0):

@maress great idea!

Some details what I had to do:

- in lib JAR

  - `beans.xml`: set `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"`
  - annotate all "public" components with `@Alternative` **and** one `@...Scoped`
  - annotate classes containing producer methods with a `@...Scoped` and the producer method with `@Alternative` and `@Produces`
  - produced classes are not required to be annotated with `@Alternative`
- in app JAR / WAR

  - `beans.xml`: list all required components and producer from lib JAR as `<alternative>`

Comment: Played around a bit with that approach and noticed that it is working only as long as no injection is used inside the lib JAR. 

Because then you have to add all Alternatives to the beans.xml of the lib JAR which makes control by the app JAR/WAR impossible.